# How to timeout subprocess in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a simple Python threading example like below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    threads = 5
    def run_in_threads(self, variable1_list, variable2):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
            pool = {executor.submit(self.run, variable1, variable2) for variable1 in variable1_list}
            concurrent.futures.wait(pool)

    def run(self, variable1, variable2):
        t = SingleThread(scf_file_path, variable2)
        t.start()
        t.join()

class SingleThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, variable1, variable2):
        logger.debug("Single thread init.")
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.my_variable = my_variable

    def run(self):
        logger.debug("Single thread started.")
        # command = my long methond, e.g. subprocess
        p = subprocess.Popen(command)
        p.wait()
        logger.debug("Single thread ended.")
```

Problem is that sometimes subprocess command is stuck and then the whole process is stopped (next part of the script can't be run).

Could you please verify this piece of code and give a hint, how to proceed with force killing thread if time reached limit e.g. 1 minute?

Comment: Do not use `p.wait()` that blocks. Instead have a while loop that polls the subprocess and also checks for the timeout.

Comment: [`Popen.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) takes an optional timeout parameter since Python 3.3.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa good point. I think it will resolve my problem. 
I'll remove p.wait and instead of it, I'll add a new "timeout" parameter to SingleThread __init__. Then in while loop in the run method, I can check if a time limit was reached. Thank you very much. And what do you think about the rest of the code? Is that more or less okay?

Comment: @shmee, your hint is even simpler. Thanks.

Comment: @shmee Please feel to promote to a full answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @shmee for your hint. Adding timeout to subprocess.wait method is the simplest solution:

```
def run(self):
    logger.debug("Single thread started.")
    # command = my long methond, e.g. subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen(command)
    p.wait(timeout=60)  # <===
    logger.debug("Single thread ended.")
```